# Zend Framework CSS / JS minifier-obfuscator?

Tags: javascript, css, zend-framework, compression, obfuscation

I am working on project which is having more than 10 CSS + JS files.

I want to minify/compress/obfuscate CSS and JS.

One approach is I can do this manually.

But apart from manual effort is there any function/method available in **Zend Framework** to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wrote a shell script that runs all the files through [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and then bundle them all together. It may look complex initially but it's not. This script ended up being our one-command-deployment for our app.

This shell does plenty of other thing specific to our backend architecture(git, Erlang,...) so I can't extract this specific part easily. But Yahoo's doc is well done.

Comment: I will consider your solution and will let you know how feasible it was in my case. Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) I have used it in several ZF projects. Just install it in /public_html/min it will then minify and compress css and javascript on the fly and has a cache feature. On the whole the peformance is very good and the script has a small footprint.

Comment: We're using this too (it comes with ZF helpers) and it is working great.

Answer (score 0):

As Mic suggest ,its very good to YUI + Shell command and  i can add another suggestion outside of ZF field 
google pagespeed mod has many filter than can achieve your goals easily

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-js-minify.html

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/filter-css-rewrite.html

Comment: Thx for your answer. Will let you know whether it worked for me or not after a test.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it yet, but [bundle-phu](https://github.com/hobodave/bundle-phu) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mic suggestion is nice, but for me it is much easier to use management/build tool like maven.apache.org (for [php](http://www.php-maven.org/)) to do this stuff and a much more required automation (for instance testing). And I'm using self written tool for js obfuscation [cactus](https://github.com/nbabinski/Cactus), which can be used as separate console tool as well as maven plugin.